# Dockerize a Rails 6 app with AWS RDS database and one local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-rds

I'm just getting to know Docker and specifically how to dockerize an existing Rails 6 application to be deployed as an AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've followed some tutorials but still a bit confused how my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file should look if I'm using 2 databases: one already created AWS RDS mysql database and one local Postgresql database. The local one doesn't have security credentials (I think I might need to create a new one on deployment to EC2?) but my AWS RDS database does. These security credentials are stored in `Rails credentials`. Here is how my `database.yml` looks right now:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: requests
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
  cast: false 
  port: 3306


development:
  aws:
    <<: *default
  local:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: tml_local 
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>


production:
  aws:
  <<: *default
  local:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: tml_local 
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>



test: 
  aws:
  <<: *default
  local:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: tml_local 
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

my Docker file is a template for Ruby 2.6.5 from Docker hub:

```
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        gmp-dev

# skip installing gem documentation
RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p /usr/local/etc; \
    { \
        echo 'install: --no-document'; \
        echo 'update: --no-document'; \
    } >> /usr/local/etc/gemrc

ENV RUBY_MAJOR 2.6
ENV RUBY_VERSION 2.6.5
ENV RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 d5d6da717fd48524596f9b78ac5a2eeb9691753da5c06923a6c31190abe01a62

# some of ruby's build scripts are written in ruby
#   we purge system ruby later to make sure our final image uses what we just built
# readline-dev vs libedit-dev: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11869 and https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/75
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .ruby-builddeps \
        autoconf \
        bison \
        bzip2 \
        bzip2-dev \
        ca-certificates \
        coreutils \
        dpkg-dev dpkg \
        gcc \
        gdbm-dev \
        glib-dev \
        libc-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        ncurses-dev \
        openssl \
        openssl-dev \
        procps \
        readline-dev \
        ruby \
        tar \
        xz \
        yaml-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    ; \
    \
    wget -O ruby.tar.xz "https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/${RUBY_MAJOR%-rc}/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION.tar.xz"; \
    echo "$RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 *ruby.tar.xz" | sha256sum --check --strict; \
    \
    mkdir -p /usr/src/ruby; \
    tar -xJf ruby.tar.xz -C /usr/src/ruby --strip-components=1; \
    rm ruby.tar.xz; \
    \
    cd /usr/src/ruby; \
    \
# https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/196
# https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14387#note-13 (patch source)
# https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14387#note-16 ("Therefore ncopa's patch looks good for me in general." -- only breaks glibc which doesn't matter here)
    wget -O 'thread-stack-fix.patch' 'https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/download/7081/0001-thread_pthread.c-make-get_main_stack-portable-on-lin.patch'; \
    echo '3ab628a51d92fdf0d2b5835e93564857aea73e0c1de00313864a94a6255cb645 *thread-stack-fix.patch' | sha256sum --check --strict; \
    patch -p1 -i thread-stack-fix.patch; \
    rm thread-stack-fix.patch; \
    \
# hack in "ENABLE_PATH_CHECK" disabling to suppress:
#   warning: Insecure world writable dir
    { \
        echo '#define ENABLE_PATH_CHECK 0'; \
        echo; \
        cat file.c; \
    } > file.c.new; \
    mv file.c.new file.c; \
    \
    autoconf; \
    gnuArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)"; \
# the configure script does not detect isnan/isinf as macros
    export ac_cv_func_isnan=yes ac_cv_func_isinf=yes; \
    ./configure \
        --build="$gnuArch" \
        --disable-install-doc \
        --enable-shared \
    ; \
    make -j "$(nproc)"; \
    make install; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-network --virtual .ruby-rundeps \
        $runDeps \
        bzip2 \
        ca-certificates \
        libffi-dev \
        procps \
        yaml-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    ; \
    apk del --no-network .ruby-builddeps; \
    \
    cd /; \
    rm -r /usr/src/ruby; \
# verify we have no "ruby" packages installed
    ! apk --no-network list --installed \
        | grep -v '^[.]ruby-rundeps' \
        | grep -i ruby \
    ; \
    [ "$(command -v ruby)" = '/usr/local/bin/ruby' ]; \
# rough smoke test
    ruby --version; \
    gem --version; \
    bundle --version

# install things globally, for great justice
# and don't create ".bundle" in all our apps
ENV GEM_HOME /usr/local/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_PATH="$GEM_HOME" \
    BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1 \
    BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG="$GEM_HOME"
# path recommendation: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6469#issuecomment-383235438
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$BUNDLE_PATH/gems/bin:$PATH
# adjust permissions of a few directories for running "gem install" as an arbitrary user
RUN mkdir -p "$GEM_HOME" && chmod 777 "$GEM_HOME"
# (BUNDLE_PATH = GEM_HOME, no need to mkdir/chown both)

CMD [ "irb" ]
```

So based on the following bare minimum `docker-compose.yml` file, what needs to be implemented to host 2 db in the Rails 6 app. BTW, my app uses Webpacker for CSS.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webapp:
    build: ./dir
```